# QGridLayout set maximum column width

Tags: c++, qt, width, max

Is it possible to somehow set the maximum width that a QGridLayout column can expand to?
If I set a maximum width to the widgets inside a column, the column keeps growing even after the widget size limit is reached.

I'm fairly new to Qt, so maybe I'm missing something... in WPF it was a piece of cake (by setting the MaxWidth property of a ColumnDefinition object).

Answer (score -4):

i think that you should insert a layout that contain the widjet into the QGridLayout :

```
>     QHboxLayout * WidgetLayout = new QHboxLayout();
>     WidgetLayout->addWidget(Your Widget)
>     
>     YourGridLayout->addLayout(WidgetLayout , /*your widjet Positionn Goes here */) // instead of adding your Widjet to the GridLayout , add the layout that u have created using the methode addLayout
```

i hope it helps